# Is the product of two derivative functions still a derivative function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is the product of two derivative functions still a derivative function? I.e., given two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$, is there always a differentiable function $k$ with $f'g'= k'$  ?

Comment: Are you asking, given differentiable $f,g$, is there a function $k$ such that $f' \times g' = k'$?

Comment: What is a derivative function?

Comment: If f is a derivative function, then there exist a g' = f.

Comment: Sure it is. The derivative of $sinx$ is $cosx$ and the derivative of $2x$ is $2$ and $2cosx$ is the derivative of another function, namely $2sinx$. It has got nothing to do with the product rule though...

Comment: @imranfat: That is just one example, not a proof.

Comment: By the way, I think this is an interesting question, no idea why it got downvoted.

Comment: @LukasGeyer. Edit has taken place....Ignore my post please...

Comment: @imranfat: This edit clearly completely changed the question, so I reverted it and clarified the question myself.

Comment: Try to give a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule

Comment: In better language, I think you mean to ask : Is the product of two derivatives always integrable ?

Comment: @JaideepKhare: No, being a derivative is not equivalent to being integrable, and worse than that, it is neither sufficient nor necessary.

Comment: Why so @LukasGeyer?If  $~\exists$ a function $k$ such that $f' \cdot g'=k' \implies \int {f' \cdot g'}=k$

Comment: @Jaideep:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function:  The point is that $f'\cdot g'$ need not be integrable.

Comment: @JaideepKhare: Derivatives can be unbounded, and functions with jump discontinuities are integrable but not derivatives of differentiable functions.

Comment: LukasGeyer and @JasonDeVito , Thanks! Today I learnt something new.

Comment: Interestingly, several research papers have been written on this topic. See the  expository survey [*Some aspects of products of derivatives*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324182) by Andrew M. Bruckner, Jan Mařík, and Clifford E. Weil [**American Mathematical Monthly** 99 #2 (February 1992), 134-145].

Comment: @Dave:  Personally, I think you promote that comment to an answer.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: I don't have time to write more now (the comment by itself probably isn't enough for an answer), but if Lukas Geyer wishes to incorporate my comment as an addition to his answer, that would be fine with me.

Answer (score 8):

The answer in general is no, here is a counterexample, where we use the same function $f(x) = g(x) = x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$. This function is differentiable on the whole real line with $f'(x) = 2x \sin \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{x} \cos \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f'(0)=0$. However, the product $f'(x)g'(x) = f'(x)^2$ satisfies $\int_0^1 f'(x)^2 \, dx = +\infty$, so if there was a function $k$ with $k'(x) = f'(x)^2$, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (using the fact that $k'$ is continuous everywhere except at $0$), we would get $k(1) - k(0) = +\infty$, so there can not be such a function $k$.

The integral divergence is not trivial to see, but it follows from the facts that $f'(x)^2 \ge 0$, that the "envelope" of $f'(x)^2$ grows like $\frac{4}{x^2}$, with $\int_0^1 \frac{4}{x^2} \, dx = +\infty$, and that $f$ oscillates somewhat regularly.

---

**ADDENDUM:** Thanks to Dave L. Renfro for pointing out the survey article [Some aspects of products of derivatives](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324182?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Andrew M. Bruckner, Jan Mařík, and Clifford E. Weil [American Mathematical Monthly 99 #2 (February 1992), 134-145]. It summarizes some related research motivated by this question. In the introduction they point to a counterexample given in the paper [Some properties of derivative functions](https://eudml.org/doc/212962) by Witold Wilkosz [Fundamenta Mathematicae, vol. 2(1), (1921), 145-154]. Witosz shows that there exists a function $f$ such that $f'(x) = \cos \frac1x$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f'(0)=0$, but that there does not exist a function $k$ such that $k'(x) = \cos^2 \frac1x$ for $x \ne 0$ and $k'(0)=0$. This example also shows that counterexamples with bounded derivatives exist.

In order to see why $\cos^2 \frac1x$ is not a derivative, here is a slightly simpler argument stolen from the article [When Is the Product of Two Derivatives a Derivative?](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691331?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Michael W. Botsko [Mathematics Magazine, 
vol. 65(3), (1992), 186-187]. Let $F(x) = -x^2 \sin \frac1x$ for $x \ne 0$, and $F(0)=0$. Then $F'(x) = -2x \sin \frac1x + \cos \frac1x$ for $x \ne 0$ and $F'(0)=0$. The function $h(x) = x \mapsto -2x \sin \frac1x$ is continuous (with $h(0)=0$), so it is a derivative by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. This shows that there exists a differentiable function $f$ with $f'(x) = \cos \frac1x$ for $x \ne 0$, and $f'(0)=0$. A similar argument with $\cos$ swapped with $\sin$ shows that there exists a differentiable function $g$ with $g'(x) = \sin \frac1x$ and $g'(0)=0$. If we assume that there exist differentiable functions $k$ and $l$ with $k'(x) = f'(x)^2$ and $l'(x) = g'(x)^2$, then $k'(x) + l'(x) = \cos^2 \frac1x + \sin^2 \frac1x = 1$ for $x \ne 0$, and $k'(0)+l'(0)=0$. This implies that the function $m(x) = k(x) + l(x)$ is differentiable with $m'(x) = 1$ for $x \ne 0$, and $m'(0)=0$. However, it is easy to see that no such function exists.

Strictly speaking, this argument only shows that one of $f'(x)^2$ and $g'(x)^2$ is not a derivative, but it is not too hard to show that neither of them is (since they are almost the same function.)

Comment: I am probably missing something simple, but why does the fact that $f'(x)^2\geq 0$ and $\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\; dx = \infty$ imlply $f'(x)^2$ is not the derivative of anything?

Comment: Because if $k'(x) = f'(x)^2$, this would imply that $k(1) - k(0) = + \infty$, either using the fact that $f'(x)^2$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ together with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, or the general fact that for an increasing function $k$ one always has $k(b) - k(a) \ge \int_a^b k'(x) \, dx$.

Comment: That makes sense: I was missing the (obvious) fact that  $f'(x)^2$ is continuous away from $0$, so things work out nicely on $[\epsilon,1]$ for any positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: Feel free to copy and paste my comment (to the question itself) as an addition to your answer.