# Existence of the derivative of a function which is the product of two differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given $g,h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable functions on their entire domain, and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ prove that if  $h(x_0)=0$,then  $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$  **if and only if** ${g(x_0)h'(x_0)}=0$ .

It is obvious that f's derivative in ${x_0}$ if exists it is going to be $g(x_0)h'(x_0)$ but I do not understand why the derivative exists in ${x_0}$ if and only if ${g(x_0)h'(x_0)}=0$

Comment: Are you sure about the hypotheses? With the given problem, an answer would be: $g$ and $h$ are both differentiable in $x_0$, and so is $f$, according to the product rule. End.

Comment: The product of two derivative is not necessary differentiable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210367/is-the-product-of-two-derivative-functions-still-a-derivative-function

Comment: @Harry49, You completely missed the point of the problem,  please read the link I posted. My comment was wrong stated by the link clarifies. The product of two functions with derivatives is not necessary differentiable.

Comment: The linked post states that the product of two *derivatives* is not necessarily the derivative of a function, which is a correct statement. Your question asks whether the product of two *differentiable functions* is differentiable, which is something completely different (cf. [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)).