# Existence of antiderivative.

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

Let's assume that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have antiderivatives on some interval.
Does $h(x) = g(x)f(x)$ necessary has derivative on the same interval?

I'm assuming not, but any hint for what should I look in this functions will be helpful!

Comment: By “have an antiderivative” you mean “have an antiderivative expressed by elementary functions “?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210367/is-the-product-of-two-derivative-functions-still-a-derivative-function

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s not always true. Consider $f(x)=|x-1|$ and $g(x)=|x-2|$ on the interval $[0,3]$. Clearly, their antiderivatives exist in this interval but $h(x)=|x-1| \ |x-2|$ has sharp non-differentiable edges at $x=1,2$. This picture illustrates it: [image]